# Is there a way to this unix Vim task in less than 10 keypresses(inlcuding ZZ)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim

Task:
In it your task
is to change the text that gets opened in Vim to the following:

```
// comments
// yay comments
// so informative, the information is really yes
// wowowowowow
// wel well
// and that's how the allocator works
```

Hint: To close Vim and save the file very quickly from NORMAL mode can be done by pressing ZZ.

Text in Vim:

```
/*
 * comments
 * yay comments
 * so informative, the information is really yes
 * wowowowowow
 * wel well
 * and that's how the allocator works
 */
```

I know to solve this in 10 keypresses using: Ctrl-v + Gr/ + dd + G. + ZZ = 10 keypresses.(Ctrl-v counts as 1).However I was wondering if it is actually possible to do this in less than keypresses, if so then how.

Comment: Why would you count the keystrokes to begin with?

Comment: @mattb it actually doesn't need that extra / in the Gr/ step , as I tried it and ti worked perfectly and yes Esc does count as a keypress.

Comment: @romainl The task was to do it as efficiently as possible and our TAs stated that it might be possible to do it in less than 10 keypresses, so I was really curious how, as they wouldn't tell us because it was bonus task.

Comment: Ah I have `set nostartofline` in my .vimrc, which is not the default, so I got different behaviour from your solution (not because of the single slash, but because the `ctrl+v` + `G` only highlighted the 1st column.

Comment: @pEpOo You might like https://www.vimgolf.com/ !